# How to create nested if in Excel function

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

i have below formula now i want to add extra if so if A2 is not present in Sheet1  show "NoData"

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDEX(Sheet1!$N$2:$N$205,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$205,0)),$K2,1)),"Match","NoMatch")
```

Comment: I would probably start the formula with IF(ISBLANK(A2),"No Data",(Your Formula))

Comment: newer versions of excel `IFS()` which is supposed to make `IF()` nesting easier to read...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the formula to:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDEX(Sheet1!$N$2:$N$205,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$205,0)),$K2,1)),"Match",IF(Sheet1!A2="","NoData","NoMatch"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Just add an `IF()` test for that before the whole thing:

```
=IF($A2="","NoData",
```

IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(INDEX(Sheet1!$N$2:$N$205,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$C$2:$C$205,0)),$K2,1)),"Match","NoMatch")  )

The rest is a pretty tight set of lookups to achieve your main goal, so there isn't a really good way to fit it into the existing material. Which is fine. Just add the test at the start.

There's no good point to `ISBLANK()` since you presumably want ANY lack of lookup data to be the trigger including the possibility of A2 having a formula itself that happens to return nothing instead some value. If you never would have such a thing, well, it'd be "OK" but it's still a function and takes more Excel work to evaluate than `$A2=""` does. It would NEVER matter, but, you know... global warming will go away on its own, but not for 20,000 years. We all have to do our parts to speed that up.